# Regex that accepts only Video file or Office doc file or PDF file or .zip file

Tags: regex

I need Regex that accepts only following files
Video file
Office doc
file
PDF file
.zip file.
Thanks,

Comment: Regex works on text, not files.  Can you expand your question?  And show things that you've already tried?

Comment: What have you tried? We're not going to do your work for you. Also, considering that you just asked a second regex question 10 minutes ago, I think it might be in your best interest to learn how to make them yourself. Both of your regex questions have been relatively trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small demo with egrep:

```
C:\tmp
>cat filelist.txt
file1.txt
file2.doc
file3.DOC
file4.jpg
file5.JPG
file6.pdf
file7.jsf
file8.php
file9.java

C:\tmp
>cat filelist.txt | egrep -i "(^.*\.doc|^.*\.pdf)"
file2.doc
file3.DOC
file6.pdf
```

If you are talking about looking inside the files to check them, that is a little more complex.

It will make a difference as to what language you are writing in, because there is some variations
on the regex implementations.